# what does it mean to mention the original array after an else operator?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am studying by looking at different answers for question in freecodecamp and I came across this one that I can't figure out the last part:

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
    const flat = [].concat(...arr);
    return flat.some(Array.isArray) ? steamrollArray(flat) : flat;
  }
  
  console.log(steamrollArray([[3, [[4]]]]));
```

Why does it say "flat" after the "else :", like what does that mean?
It just mention the original array, there is nothing going on like .push() or other methods.

Comment: Do you understand the syntax of the conditional operator?  `cond ? truthy_value : falsey_value`  if `flat.some(Array.isArray)` is truthy, then it returns `steamrollArray(flat)` otherwise it just returns `flat`.  (Probably because it makes no sense to further steamroll it because it doesn't contain any arrays.)

Comment: The function either returns `steamrollArray(flat)` or `flat`.  Depending on `flat.some(Array.isArray)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line with the return basically does:

1. If at least one item inside the `flat` array is another Array, it will process `steamrollArray` (so this is a recursive function)
2. If the `some` method returns false, it will return the flat variable as it is. The flat variable will be eventually a number, meaning `.some` will return false and exit one level of the recursiveness and so on.

Running the code makes it easier to understand, as well as the documentation on the [.some() JS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```js
function steamrollArray(arr) {
    const flat = [].concat(...arr);
    return flat.some(Array.isArray) ? steamrollArray(flat) : flat;
  }
  
 console.log(steamrollArray([[3, [[4]]]]));
 //output = [3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

it is referring to the original flat variable in this line:

`const flat = [].concat(...arr);`

which will be returned if this line is false:

`flat.some(Array.isArray)`

Comment: I’m sorry I still don't visualise.

Answer (score 0):

The key is the `return` preceding the expression: `flat` is not being modified because it is flat and is ready to be returned as the final value of the function.

I think the function can be reworded more clearly like this:

```
function steamrollArray(arr) {
    const flat = [].concat(...arr);
    if (flat.some(Array.isArray)) { // check if the array is not flat
        return steamrollArray(flat); // if it is not flat, process it more
    }
    return flat; // return a completely flat array
}
  
console.log(steamrollArray([[3, [[4]]]]));
```